# Getting 404 for CORS request to Web API only in Chrome and only on server

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, cors, http-status-code-404, preflight

I'm trying to POST data from a website to a Web API endpoint on the same server with the same domain name, but a different port number. It works with IE11 both locally and on our test server, but Chrome only works locally. On the test server I get a 404 error. As far as I can tell, it qualifies as a "simple" request, however the 404 error shows the HTTP Method was "OPTIONS", so it must be making a preflight request and failing on that.

```
zone.js:2933 OPTIONS http://example.com:8001/api/search/quickSearch?v=1.35.2664 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2933
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2966
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12587
sendReq @ angular.js:12332
serverRequest @ angular.js:12084
processQueue @ angular.js:16832
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16876
$digest @ angular.js:17971
(anonymous) @ static.js:1502
schedulerFn @ core.js:4351
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:240
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:187
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:128
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:92
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4319
checkStable @ core.js:4718
onLeave @ core.js:4797
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4747
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:488
timer @ zone.js:2040
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2056
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2072
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
setTimeout @ lodash.js:6663
timerExpired @ lodash.js:10388
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:488
timer @ zone.js:2040
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2056
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2072
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
setTimeout @ lodash.js:6663
leadingEdge @ lodash.js:10358
debounced @ lodash.js:10425
fn @ VM445:4
$eval @ angular.js:18161
(anonymous) @ angular.js:25998
(anonymous) @ angular.js:28813
forEach @ angular.js:403
$$writeModelToScope @ angular.js:28811
writeToModelIfNeeded @ angular.js:28804
(anonymous) @ angular.js:28798
validationDone @ angular.js:28723
processAsyncValidators @ angular.js:28706
$$runValidators @ angular.js:28650
$$parseAndValidate @ angular.js:28791
$commitViewValue @ angular.js:28757
(anonymous) @ angular.js:28898
$eval @ angular.js:18161
$apply @ angular.js:18261
$$debounceViewValueCommit @ angular.js:28897
$setViewValue @ angular.js:28875
listener @ angular.js:24822
dispatch @ jquery.js:4737
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4549
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
(index):1 Failed to load http://example.com:8001/api/search/quickSearch?v=1.35.2664: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Here's what my Global.asax looks like to enable CORS requests:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootUri"].TrimEnd('/'));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "30");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With");

        // If a preflight request, end it so we don't fetch data.
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting a 404 and how can I fix it?

Comment: You probably want to also include a code snippet showing the part of your frontend JavaScript code that’s initiating the request. If it actually qualified a simple request, your browser wouldn’t be sending that preflight OPTIONS. And regardless, the real problem seems to be that the server the request is being sent to is misconfigured to incorrectly respond to OPTIONS requests with a 404, and the Global.asax code snippet in the question does not seem to be fixing that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari may also make preflight OPTIONS requests for non-GET methods (e.g. POST).

I'm not sure what `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootUri"].TrimEnd('/')` resolves to - the ACAO response headers must either be an asterisk or (as it appears you're trying to do) an FQDN, including the scheme and port (if the port isn't 80 or 443) - so in your case, it must have an EXACT value of "http://example.com:8001". It's much simpler to simply mirror back the value of the Origin request header (which will have that value).

Can you post the request and response headers?

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue calling a method

$.ajax({
url:'/Home/Read'

Use

$.ajax({
url:'../Home/Read'